# return-statement with no value in function returning void: HxScout with openfl

Tags: android, haxe, openfl, lime-haxe

I'm developing an app for android using openfl. I could successfully compile for android before trying to use HxScout.

But following instructions on hxscout.com, when I try to test my app with this command:
haxelib run lime test android -Dtelemetry

I get the following error:
./src/hxtelemetry/CppHxTelemetry.cpp:233: error: return-statement with no value, in function returning 'Void'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just pushed the fix to both [git](https://github.com/jcward/hxtelemetry/commits/master) and [haxelib](http://lib.haxe.org/p/hxtelemetry/0.3.5/) (hxtelemetry v0.3.5). I think there were issues with different versions of haxe/hxcpp wanting [different styles of returns](https://github.com/jcward/hxtelemetry/issues/45#issuecomment-259719503).

Anyway, LMK if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in this issue [here](https://github.com/jcward/hxtelemetry/issues/46) on github